# MySql. Can anyone answer why this produces results out of expected range?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT mt.mB, mt.UTC
from thundersense mt

where mt.mB =
    (   SELECT max(mB)
        FROM thundersense mt2
        WHERE mt2.UTC > 1490569200
    )
```

This produces a few results, but most are before the required date. How do I make this select data and time for the current day. I'm sure this has been asked, but I cant track it down...

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

The filter needs to be included in the outer query as well...

```
SELECT mt.mB, mt.UTC
from thundersense mt
where mt.UTC > 1490569200
and mt.mB =
    (   SELECT max(mB)
        FROM thundersense mt2
        WHERE mt2.UTC > 1490569200
    );
```

This following query generates the max(mB) one time instead of for each row...

```
select mt.mB,
       mt.UTC
from thundersense mt
join (  select max(mB) as mB
        from thundersense
        where UTC > 1490569200 ) as max on (mt.mB = max.mB)
where mt.UTC > 1490569200;
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me with two working examples. My code returned ALL the times it was the same as the chosen period maximum, is that correct?

Comment: If all mB occur within the chosen period, then yes (I don't know your data).  The queries above will filter older data out.  You can replace 1490569200 with unix_timestamp(curdate()) if you are looking for the current date - this will filter entries older than today.